# index ul li touchstart

Tags: jquery, html

can you retrieve the index of ul li like with touchstart , like you can with a click function ?

```
<ul id = "list" ontouchstart="touchStart(event,'issues')">
                    <li>
                        <h1>header 1</h1>
                        <p>tekst1</p>
                        <a class="next" href="#">next</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>header 1</h1>
                        <p>tekst1</p>
                        <a class="next" href="#">next</a>
                    </li>
                     <li>
                        <h1>header 1</h1>
                        <p>tekst1</p>
                        <a class="next" href="#">next</a>
                    </li>
</ul>
```

for the click on the a tag , i use :

```
$('#list li a').click(function()  {

var ind =  $(this).closest('li').index()   ;
});
```

but for touchsmart, it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using `touchstart` on `ul` component and you are trying to find the `closet` >  `li` while sitting at the `ul` `touchstart`. So, simply change the handler to desired `<a>` tag and fetch the index as done in `click` handler ,

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <h1>header 1</h1>
        <p>tekst1</p> <a class="next" href="#" ontouchstart="touchStart(event,'issues')">next</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>header 1</h1>
        <p>tekst1</p> <a class="next" href="#" ontouchstart="touchStart(event,'issues')">next</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>header 1</h1>
        <p>tekst1</p> <a class="next" href="#" ontouchstart="touchStart(event,'issues')">next</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

And, this will workout.